# Strange ? icon in MacOS Sierra in dropdown

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I have a strange minor error. Im using MacOS Sierra, and in many situations, regardless of app, say in drop-downs, say in Calendar, I get a **question mark** appear near the selected item. If I was in reminders it would be there as well.. This happened over the past week or so.

[image: Calendar]

Maybe it's a font issue, I'm not sure but I wouldn't have a clue as to how to approach this. I don't have any functionality issues or anything else, just that the circle that should be in lieu of that question mark is not showing.

[image: reminders]

Any guidance would be super awesome.

Answer (score 4):

There is a similar question on apple.stackexchange.com: [Check mark disappeared from dropdowns](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/262680/122152).
According to the [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/262741/122152) by user grgarside, this issue can be fixed by:

- Opening Font Book.app and choosing File → Restore Standard Fonts.  It might be necessary to reboot

I had the same issue and this fixed it for me.

According to [this comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262680/check-mark-disappeared-from-dropdowns#comment329655_262741) by user bosmacs, it might also be necessary to rebuild the font cache with the following command: 
`sudo atsutil databases -remove`